# TSQL Uncommon query aggregation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'll try to present my problem as short as possible.
I have a table which contains row with values for each day and type. I need to select changes for type on all values. I will try ti present this by 2 queries.

Full set looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-01', 120) Date, 0 Type,  0 Val1,  5 Val2
  UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-01', 120) Date, 1 Type,  3 Val1,  5 Val2
  UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-02', 120) Date, 0 Type,  0 Val1,  5 Val2
  UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-02', 120) Date, 1 Type,  3 Val1,  5 Val2
  UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-03', 120) Date, 0 Type,  0 Val1,  5 Val2
  UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-03', 120) Date, 1 Type,  3 Val1,  7 Val2
  UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-04', 120) Date, 0 Type,  1 Val1,  5 Val2
  UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-04', 120) Date, 1 Type,  4 Val1,  7 Val2
  UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-05', 120) Date, 0 Type,  1 Val1,  5 Val2
  UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-05', 120) Date, 1 Type,  5 Val1,  7 Val2
  UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-06', 120) Date, 1 Type,  3 Val1,  5 Val2
  UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-06', 120) Date, 0 Type,  0 Val1,  5 Val2
) X
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Now the idea is this, I need to find all first dates when val1 and val2 changes. val1 and val2 can have same value as some time earlier so it is a change from a previous state from this type. I expect output to be something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-01', 120) Date, 0 Type,  0 Val1,  5 Val2
  UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-01', 120) Date, 1 Type,  3 Val1,  5 Val2
  --UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-02', 120) Date, 0 Type,  0 Val1,  5 Val2
  --UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-02', 120) Date, 1 Type,  3 Val1,  5 Val2
  --UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-03', 120) Date, 0 Type,  0 Val1,  5 Val2
  UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-03', 120) Date, 1 Type,  3 Val1,  7 Val2
  UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-04', 120) Date, 0 Type,  1 Val1,  5 Val2
  UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-04', 120) Date, 1 Type,  4 Val1,  7 Val2
  --UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-05', 120) Date, 0 Type,  1 Val1,  5 Val2
  UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-05', 120) Date, 1 Type,  5 Val1,  7 Val2
  UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-06', 120) Date, 1 Type,  3 Val1,  5 Val2
  UNION SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-06', 120) Date, 0 Type,  0 Val1,  5 Val2
) X
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Is there any way to make this behave this way without dramatic performance loss?

Comment: I cannot understand logic, why do you skip 3rd row, but output last row, both have 0, 5 as values?

Comment: Because at 2015-01-04 there was a 1 and 5, so at 2015-01-06 we have a change. Currently I'm joining to previous date using CTE views, table is enormous and it takes hours to find changes.

Comment: Please tag your question with the appropriate SQL Server version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. It always helps to specify the database software and version.

Comment: Unless you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, which has `LAG/LEAD` functions it would be more efficient to do this processing in a procedural way, rather than `SQL`. You can do it in `O(n)` using cursor. Set based `SQL` without `LAG/LEAD` would be `O(n*n)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're welcome to change the sort order of the results, but I found it easier to understand when grouped by `Type`.

```
declare @Samples as Table ( EventDate Date, EventType Int, Val1 Int, Val2 Int );
insert into @Samples ( EventDate, EventType, Val1, Val2 ) values
  ( '2015-01-01', 0, 0, 5 ),
  ( '2015-01-01', 1, 3, 5 ),
  ( '2015-01-02', 0, 0, 5 ),
  ( '2015-01-02', 1, 3, 5 ),
  ( '2015-01-03', 0, 0, 5 ),
  ( '2015-01-03', 1, 3, 7 ),
  ( '2015-01-04', 0, 1, 5 ),
  ( '2015-01-04', 1, 4, 7 ),
  ( '2015-01-05', 0, 1, 5 ),
  ( '2015-01-05', 1, 5, 7 ),
  ( '2015-01-06', 1, 3, 5 ),
  ( '2015-01-06', 0, 0, 5 );
select * from @Samples;

with NumberedSamples ( EventOccurrence, EventDate, EventType, Val1, Val2 ) as
  ( select Row_Number() over ( partition by EventType order by EventDate ) as EventOccurrence,
    EventDate, EventType, Val1, Val2
    from @Samples ),
  StateChanges ( EventOccurrence, EventDate, EventType, Val1, Val2, Skip ) as
  ( -- Start with the initial Val1/Val2 pair for each Date/Type combination.
  select EventOccurrence, EventDate, EventType, Val1, Val2, 0
    from NumberedSamples
    where EventOccurrence = 1
  union all
  -- Add each subsequent occurrence for each event and determine whether the values changed.
  select NS.EventOccurrence, NS.EventDate, NS.EventType, NS.Val1, NS.Val2,
    case when NS.Val1 = SC.Val1 and NS.Val2 = SC.Val2 then 1 else 0 end
    from StateChanges as SC inner join
      NumberedSamples as NS on NS.EventType = SC.EventType and
      NS.EventOccurrence = SC.EventOccurrence + 1 )
  select *
    from StateChanges
    where Skip = 0
    order by EventType, EventDate;
```